# Can someone help me to figure out how to read my file from ":" (not included) til the end of the line?

Tags: java, file, while-loop, java.util.scanner

My exercise ask to open the file sales.dat, and read only the number part of every line. All of this using the Scanner class

i've tried with while loops, for loops and every other possible solution on my book but none works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nomeFile = "sales.dat";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        System.out.println("Il file "+ nomeFile + "\ncontiene le righe seguenti:\n");

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(nomeFile));
            inputStream.useDelimiter(":");
            while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String riga = inputStream.nextLine();
                System.out.println(riga);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Errore nell'apertura del file " + nomeFile);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Expected: if line is `San Francisco: 198870.32` it must read and print only `198870.32`

```
Actual: San Francisco: 198870.32
        Chicago: no report received
        New York: 298734.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
inputStream.useDelimiter(":");
```

You may now read the whole line and then use `split()`.

```
String riga = inputStream.nextLine(); //San Francisco: 198870.32
System.out.println(riga.split(":")[1].trim());
```

this should give you `198870.32`.

Comment: Thank you so much, so clear to understand! Now i just need other two things to fix. First, what you told me i need it to do for every line of the .dat file. Second, how can i transform that numeric part of the line in a double, and, then save it in a variable? Thanks again

Comment: Yes you may have to use `split()` in each line. You can convert the `String` to a `double` by using `Double.parseDouble("198870.32");`.

Comment: I don't know what to say but thank you very very much!